# Can't change a class variable within javascript function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, increment

The method, `foo()` is called, sx++ won't change. When I `alert(sx)` I get NaN. Should I define the method using prototype?

```
function fooClass(sx) {
    this.sx = sx;
    this.foo = function() {
      if(booleanIsTrue) this.sx++;
    };
}
```

*Ignore syntax errors, if any. This is not a copy paste. It is correct in my project.

Moving `sx++` out side the if statement works.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Because `sx` is not `this.sx` …?

Comment: Opps, that was a mistake on my typing part. Fixed.

Comment: _“Moving sx++ out side the if statement works”_ – well than maybe the if condition does not evaluate to true …?

Comment: @CBroe that is possible, I will test that when I get back to my project computer.

Comment: you should check your condition if(booleanIsTrue)

Comment: Yes, I think you should use prototype if only so you won't create closure(s) every time you create a fooClass. It's also better to capitalise constructor methods so you know it's not meant to be invoked. I have tried to create a as complete as possible answer about prototype and constructor functions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 Think your current problem is most likely related to the if statement, you can console.log in chrome or firefox (preferably with firebug plugin) but if you're using IE it only works after pressing F12. To see the console you can just press F12

Comment: Where is booleanIsTrue defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said this looks like a case were you would want to use the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)  instead of creating new functions for each object created by the function. That would look like this

```
var FooClass = function (sx) {
    this.sx = sx;
};

FooClass.prototype.foo = function () {
  if (booleanIsTrue) { //Where is booleanIsTrue coming from?
    this.sx++; 
  }
};


var a = new FooClass(0);
a.foo();
console.log(a.sx); //1
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you're wrong, the `this` value is the invoking object and since the OP didn't include how the function is invoked we can't see what `this` is. Function foo is a member of fooClass instances (would be better on fooClass.prototype but for other reasons) so we assume it's invokied with `fooClassInstance.foo();` the invoking object would be fooClassInstance that would have a `this.sx` member as well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 under "The this variable"

Comment: You are right it does depend on the way the function is invoked, usage of `call` or `apply`, but I am assumed as you said that it was called with `fooClassInstance.foo()`. I can see how saying that a function has an implicit `this` without stating that it's the invoking object is not clear enough. I will fix it.

Comment: I don't fully follow the first part of the answer but do agree with defining the function on the prototype. Even though that will not solve the OP's problem since he/she stated that removing the if statement would make it behave like OP expected. If I were to do `var inst=new fooClass();inst.foo();` with the code as OP provided than `this` inside the foo function would be `inst` and not window.

Comment: Oh you are right I was mixing up having the function in a variable and not attaching it to `this` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're having this problem because you're adding to the wrong variable. You want to change the class variable sx.

As someone pointed out, class is a reserved word, usually you use klass instead.

Also, you should be using {}, try entering you code into JSLint and see what it returns.

Try this out:

```
function klass(sx) {
    this.sx = sx;
    this.foo = function(booleanIsTrue) {
      if(booleanIsTrue === true) {
        this.sx++;
      }
    };
}

var a = new klass(3);
a.foo(true);
console.log(a.sx); // 4
```

Comment: did you change anything? oO

Comment: I added some code to instantiate the class and everything now, try it out!

Comment: I will try to instantiate it, but should it not log within the method. I need to change `this.sx` within the method in order to `this.render()` an object differently. All within the class.

Comment: Log within the method?